# How to make WPF Slider Thumb follow cursor from any point

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, slider

I have such slider:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" 
TickFrequency="1"
IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
IsSnapToTickEnabled="False"/>
```

I want to make next behavior:
 when MouseDown occured at any point of slider, Thumb not only moves once to that point, but also following cursor until MouseUp occurs.

Sorry if it was asked already, i couldn't find that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior will happen **only** when you drag the slider thumb itself, it is by design.

*However*, here's some code that will do it ;-)

Hook to the MouseMove event in XAML:

```
<Slider MouseMove="Slider_OnMouseMove" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"/>
```

Then insert this code:

```
private void Slider_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var slider = (Slider)sender;
        Point position = e.GetPosition(slider);
        double d = 1.0d / slider.ActualWidth * position.X;
        var p = slider.Maximum * d;
        slider.Value = p;
    }
}
```

Note :

- You might have to take margins and padding of your slider into account should they differ, I haven't.
- This was done on an horizontal slider.
- Minimum value of my slider was 0, make sure to adjust the calculation should your minimum be negative.
- Finally, it does seem to work only when IsMoveToPointEnabled is set.

Comment: I've updated my code to use ActualWidth instead of Width as sometimes it is a NaN value what causes an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Aybe's solution works better in the thumb_MouseMove event.

```
void timelineThumb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
     {
         var thumb = sender as Thumb;

         Point pos = e.GetPosition(uiVideoPlayerTimelineSlider);
         double d = 1.0d / uiVideoPlayerTimelineSlider.ActualWidth * pos.X;
         uiVideoPlayerTimelineSlider.Value = uiVideoPlayerTimelineSlider.Maximum * d;

     }
}
```

Comment: It's good, but a check and code for Slider.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical would make it golden.