# Operating a slider inside a ListBox by touch

Tags: wpf, listbox, touch

I have an `ItemTemplate` of a `ListBoxItem` that contains a `Slider`. The UI should be operated on a touch screen. However, the slider doesn't work - the thumb cannot be dragged.

The problem can be demonstrated like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Slider Height="40" Width="300" Margin="20,10,20,10"/>
    <ListBox>
        <Slider Height="40" Width="300" Margin="20,10,20,10"/>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The slider inside the `ListBox` cannot be dragged by touch (although it works for mouse or keyboard input). The other slider outside of the `ListBox` works just fine (mouse, keyboard, touch).

What needs to be done to "enable" the slider inside the `ListBox` for touch input?

Comment: You need to edit Lisbox Template. Base template here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc278062(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: What exactly needs to be done in this template to enable the slider?

Comment: Why do you need a slider inside Listbox?

Comment: @Sajeetharan: Well, I have something like a playlist. Each item, if active, shows its replay position with a slider, which in turn can be dragged to change the replay position.

Comment: @JeffRSon it could be that the `ListBox`'s default selection behavior is interfering with touch events. If you don't need selection, use an `ItemsControl` instead of a ListBox.

Comment: *What needs to be done to "enable" the slider inside the ListBox?* It *is* enabled in my test project.

Comment: @HighCore: Just tried - unfortunately the slider cannot be dragged in an `ItemsControl` as well. It's interesting, however, that the `ItemsControl` produces "ManipulationDelta" events, which the `ListBox` did not. -- BTW, I noticed that the ListBox as well as the ItemsControl release "GotTouchCapture" events, the "standalone" slider on the other hand doesn't. So the touch events are'nt forwarded to the slider. But I don't know how I could use this information...

Comment: @Sheridan: You included the snippet above in a test project and both sliders work?

Comment: @JeffRSon to make this completely clear, do keyboard and mouse input work? Is it just touch events that aren't working?

Comment: They did both work, but then I can't test touch here.

Comment: @HighCore: Yes, exactly. Mouse and keyboard can be used without problems. Touch sometimes causes the slider to "jump" - this appears to be the case, when "TouchUp" happens on the thin slider bar. It never works on the slider thumb.

Comment: Ahhh... +1 for your question @HighCore... so finally, we are eventually provided with details of the *actual* problem. Why do we have to work so hard just to get these guys to tell us what their problems are?

Comment: @JeffRSon Sheridan is right. Please edit your question specifying that it's just touch input that's not working.

Comment: Sorry to you both - I thought "The slider inside the ListBox cannot be dragged by touch" was sufficient.

Comment: @JeffRSon I can't test touch input here, but you might want to have a look at the event sequence using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It tells you which events are raised, and which UI elements are handling them.

Comment: @HighCore: Yes, that's a big problem with touch devices - only a few people can really help because of missing hardware. In the meantime I was lucky enough to find a working solution in the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369040/slider-scrollviewer-in-a-touch-interface-not-working-properly/8946613 - obviously I missed that in the first place because it doesn't deal with ListBox or another ItemsControl. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @JeffRSon you might want to post an answer here for future readers ;)

Comment: @HighCore: Sure - I'm just about to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer of [Slider \ ScrollViewer in a touch interface not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369040/slider-scrollviewer-in-a-touch-interface-not-working-properly/8946613) will help here as well.

This is probably due to the `ListBox` and `ItemsControl` containing a `ScrollViewer` internally. Obviously this `ScrollViewer` is important to drag the `ListBox` itself (so I cannot get rid of it). However, the `ScrollViewer` can be tricked by the CustomThumb class of the other post.

Replacing the `Thumb` in the style is as easy as:

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    ...>
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <Style x:Key="SliderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
        ...
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
            ...
            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <l:CustomThumb x:Name="Thumb" .../>
                </Track.Thumb>
            </Track>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can do this by editing the style created by Expression Blend.