# How do I inherit a custom control written in C# inside of xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have a problem where a WPF slider is not functioning properly inside a scrollviewer. I believe this problem has been adressed here:

[Slider \ ScrollViewer in a touch interface not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369040/slider-scrollviewer-in-a-touch-interface-not-working-properly/8946613)

The accepted answer is telling to retemplate the slider based on the custom thumb (created in a c# class).

Unfortunately whatever I do, I get problems.

to make things more difficult my slider is based on Mahapps and I found the slider style online:

https://github.com/robertbaker/Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Slider.xaml

So, I copied the entire Slider style into my App.Xaml. So far things work...

But When I try to modify the Thumb style by doing a "BasedOn":

```
<Style x:Key="HorizontalSliderThumb" TargetType="Thumb" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomThumb}">
```

Nothing works....

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Help is appreciated !

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your xaml file

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:<Namespace of custom controls>">
```

From there you can use

```
<custom:<name of custom component> />
```

Comment: The thumb control is part of the slider. I am trying to retemplate the slider based on the customcontrol.

Comment: after adding this custom try to use:

Comment: Style x:Key="HorizontalSliderThumb" TargetType="CustomThumb"

Comment: Then I get this message: 'CustomThumb' TargetType does not match type of element 'Thumb'.

Comment: The CustomThumb is the same as declared in the other link right?
Weird, if no one answers this untill later i will get home and try this on my computer. Sorry for not being able to be more helpful at the time

Comment: Never mind, It worked ! I also had to reference customthumb from inside the slider (instead of the normal thumb) and not only set the targettype for the horizontalSliderThumb. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad i could be of help!